# Android ContentProvider with network as a data source

Tags: android, sql, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to provide in-game high-scores with custom ContentProvider. Instead of SQLite DB it will use server connection.

Now, ContentProvider's *query()*, *update()* and *delete()* methods have *selection*, *selectionArgs* and *sortOrder* params. So the question is: how do I parse them? I don't want to add heavy SQL-grammar parsing libs into this simple app.

People on the Internet mention RESTProvider: https://github.com/novoda/RESTProvider. It seemed like what I'm searching for, but turned out to be missing the relevant code.

Why do I want to use ContentProvider for high-scores in the first place? Because cursors have great support in Android, and it may be useful for my other related apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't received any response / comments, so answering question myself.

Basically, the idea in this kind of situations is to simplify the problem as much as possible. So I limited *projection* to only have column names, *selection* to consist of only `column = ?` AND-ed fragments, and required *sortOrder* to consist of `column ASC` or `column DESC` parts.

In other words, you don't want to create an SQL engine but simply a ContentProvider interface for some network data.

Answer (score 0):

The integration between your app and the ContentProvider is just through Uri's.
Therefore, as you already stated, it is not required to have SQL at all.
You just have to implement the `query(..)` method with the usual `if/switch` statements and do the network request.
Most likely, you are using `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>` in your app, the network request will be executed outside the main thread.

Now, the question is about the `<D>` type - which must be `Cursor` to comply with the Content Provider `query` method return type.
You should implement interface `Cursor` just to keep consistency on the application - your new `Cursor`-based class may be parsing JSON and returning data just like when using a SQLite cursor. You have to create maps with indexes just to simulate the `_cursor.get<Type>(_cursor.getColumnIndex(_name))`

A different approach would be to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<YourClass>`. And `YourClass` will have other methods just to simplify getting data from the actual content. Of course, you will need to accommodate something in between when creating the loader since the Content Provider returns a `Cursor`.